# Highlighting buttons in a program

Tags: after-effects, tutorial

Sorry if this question is out of content.

I'm creating tutorials on a program where I will have to highlight the location of the buttons, their functions and make it enjoyable for anyone to watch.

I use After Effects to edit my videos.

I would like the answers to be suggestions on how to achieve those goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shapes around that icon and animate it. Like enclosing the icon by a circle and animating the circle to reveal in clockwise or anticlockwise manner.

For description of that icon you can use some nice looking lower thirds and edit the the text of that lower third to describe the content.

You can search for lower thirds pack online and download for free. There are plenty of them available for free online.